# Prove that the eigenvalues of a skew-symmetric matrix are purely imaginary

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Proof idea:

$A$ is a skew symmetric matrix.

$A$ is similar to $A^t$ because every matrix is similar to it's transpose.
$$A^t = -A $$
$A$ is similar to $-A$. Let $P_{(\lambda)}$ be the characteristic polynomial.
$$P_{(A)}=P_{(-A)}=0$$
(I'm not sure about the above step)

And I also know that:  $\overline{P_{(A)}}=\overline{P_{(-A)}}=\overline0=0$

That's where I ran out of ideas. am i in the right direction?